# Can't run PHP exec() on command line

Tags: php, linux, command-line, exec

Hoping someone can help me out here. Trying to run any command using `exec()` returns 126 and displays the same error message. I've narrowed it down to this pretty minimal test case.

```
root@test:~ $ sudo -u asterisk php -r 'exec("ls /", $out, $result); var_dump($result);'
sh: /bin/ls: Permission denied
int(126)

root@test:~ $ sudo -u asterisk ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt   opt   proc  root  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var

root@test:~ $ su -lc 'php -r '\''exec("ls /", $out, $result); var_dump($result);'\' asterisk
This account is currently not available.
```

- SELinux and PHP safe mode are not enabled
- permissions are fine on `/`, `/bin/`, and `/bin/ls`
- *asterisk* is a system user created with this command: `adduser -d /var/lib/asterisk -M -r -s /sbin/nologin asterisk`
- it works fine via Apache, which runs as this user

Every attempt to run any command returns permission denied and 126 as `$?`. The PHP config is pretty much as it shipped (Scientific Linux 6.7, PHP 5.4 via Remi package.)

Would appreciate some assistance (preferably the kind that would require some arcane knowledge, not the kind that means I missed something blindingly obvious!)

Edit: I can get it to work using `su` if I give the user a login shell:

```
root@test:~ $ usermod -s /bin/bash asterisk
root@test:~ $ su -c 'php -r '\''exec("ls /", $out, $result); var_dump($result);'\' asterisk
int(0)
```

However, this isn't my code so changing all the use of `sudo` to `su` is not likely to happen. Also, there shouldn't be anything stopping PHP from running this without a login shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have enabled `sudo` option `NOEXEC`.

When this option is active, you can run command with high privilege, but cannot spawn other commands. This is (AFAIK) required to avoid an exploiter to gain a shell. Since you are using the `asterisk` user, this also makes much sense.

In your case, PHP command is granted the execution as `asterisk` user, but when it tries to spawn with `exec`, the command cannot be executed and it returns `126`.

EDIT (as in comment below)

Adding this line to sudoers will solve this issue:

```
root ALL = (ALL) EXEC: ALL
```

Comment: Ah, this is it! I have a lower level login for people to look at log files and such; I recently tightened up sudoers after doing some reading on unexpected security holes like `less`. Will check when I get to work but I'm sure this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, got it working by adding the following to `sudoers`:

    `root ALL = (ALL) EXEC: ALL`

Thanks so much, I will award the bounty in a couple of hours once it's been 24 hours.

Comment: Added your solution to the original answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your account doesn't have permission to run bash commands.

As you know `int(126)` return the status of the executed command. From the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If a command is found but is not executable, the return status is 126.

Try running `ls` directly from your `asterisk` user to see if it works.

If it doesn't work then check the permissions on your `asterisk` user and see if you have the necessary permissions. If you don't have the permissions, just use `chmod` to give your `asterisk` user permission. You should also try and create a new user and see if this command works with that user.

**Edit**: Since your `asterisk` account does not have a shell, you cannot execute shell commands from it.

Comment: As I said in the question, I ran it directly from sudo and it worked just fine; there are not permissions issues with `ls` or my root directory!

Comment: In your code sample, you run this command from `root` as `asterisk`. Try running the command directly from `asterisk`

Comment: That's what `sudo` is for. This is not a login account.

Comment: One final question. Does your `asterisk` user have a shell? In other words have you executed this command `usermod -s /sbin/nologin asterisk`

Comment: It's a system account created with `adduser -r`, so shell is set to `/sbin/nologin` at creation.

Comment: Well then how could you possibly expect to execute shell commands without a shell???

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to provide another answer to my own question a couple of years later. As the accepted answer supposed, I had set this in my file:

```
Defaults noexec
```

And I fixed this by overriding it for the root user.

But a better solution would be to apply the defaults only to the targeted user:

```
Defaults:admin noexec
```

This way the setting would not have affected the `asterisk` user I was having problems with in my question!